# Error only occurs after publishing: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, html

During development the program runs fine, but once published I noticed my elements weren't populating properly. I thought at first it was a problem with the update panels, but someone told me to use Firebug, and this is the error I see being thrown.

Again:
"Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."

My code(This part is from the web.config):

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySQLConnection"    connectionString="[myServer];[myDatabase];UID= [myID];PWD=[myPassword];"
    providerName="MySql.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

In C#, I call the connection string thusly:

```
    string connstring = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConnection"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
```

Any input on why this isn't working, or why it works in development and not once published, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT: New information

Oh my god, this is maddening.

So my program had a second web.config file, and I had previously put a connection string in that one with incorrect data. When the program ran that's what it was trying to use, and that's why it wasn't working. Or so I thought.

I found this out, of course, after thinking it was the same file, and simply trying to update it. Finally I removed the connection string from the old file altogether, and what do you know, I now know that it's using the proper connection string.

Hoo-ray for me, right? Nope.

I now know that it is using the correct connection string, and yet it is still somehow not working.

That being said, I added some better troubleshooting in, so now I have this:

```
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the             specified MySQL hosts. ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission             of type 'System.Net.SocketPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,             PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
    at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Obj ect demand, StackCrawlMark&             stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
    at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Cod eAccessPermission cap,             StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
    at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.CheckCacheRemote(EndPoin t& remoteEP, Boolean         isOverwrite)
    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx(EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean flowContext,             AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback         callback,     Object state)
    at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.CreateSocketStream (IPAddress ip, Boolean unix)
    at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(UInt32 timeout)
    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
    The action that failed was:
    Demand
    The type of the first permission that failed was:
    System.Net.SocketPermission
    The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
    MyComputer
    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnecti onStringBuilder settings)
    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnecti on()
    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
    at WordsOfPower.testing.update_words() in C:\Users\AJ\documents\visual studio         2010\Projects\WordsOfPower\WordsOfPower\WordsOfPow er.aspx.cs:line 39
```

Final Edit: I updated my web.config to use full trust.

http://support.winhost.com/KB/a657/changing-the-default-aspnet-trust-level.aspx

Comment: Lots of things to check.  First, is the connection string supposed to be the same in production and your dev?  Can your production server actually *see* the mysql box?

Comment: Just to specify: My "Production" system is webspace I purchased on winhost, and my "Dev" environment is Visual Web Studio 2010 on my personal computer.

That being said I'm connecting to the same database, so I don't know why I'd need to change the connection string at all.

I've experimented a bit with adding a port, but that just caused problems.

Comment: The error simply means that the web server cannot locate the database server.  There are LOTS of different reasons for this, for example the DB server could be behind a firewall that doesn't allow access from your host.

Comment: I think I may have figured out the issue I'm having, but I haven't quite been able to crack it yet. It looks like my web.config on the server is an old version that is incorrect. For some reason it refuses to update when I publish my program.

Comment: Unfortunately VS sometimes doesn't always publish everything you think it should.  Usually it involves a mismatch between the server date/time and your PC's date/time.  If the delta is great enough random config, aspx and some other files never get pushed.

Comment: I wish I could blame it on that, but it looks like I had 2 web.configs and they were messing each other up. That being said, that didn't fix the issue :/

I've edited my original post to reflect my new error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a trust issue.

See http://www.marthijnvandenheuvel.com/2011/04/14/fix-net-4-socketpermission-for-mysql-driver-in-medium-trust/

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was beginning to think.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the connection string in the web.config file is correct

```
<add name="STRING_CONNECTION" connectionString="Server=[SERVER];Database=[DATA BASE NAME];Uid=[USER];Pwd=[PASSWORD];" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

Comment: I just double checked that, and it looks like I'm all good on that front. Still looking, think I may have figured something out.