# Is it possible to connect to MySQL database in a remote Linux machine with Visual Studio in Windows

Tags: c#, mysql, linux, visual-studio-2010

I've been researching forever for the connecting strings (VB or C#) to connect to a remote MySQL database that is currently hosted (by Hostgator.com) in a shared linux box.  Is it possible?  If so, can anyone direct me to the codes or wizard on how to do this. I'm using 2010 Visual Studio Express on my desktop in Windows 7.  Your help would be so greatly appreciated.

Update:
I kept getting "Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style password" and after numerous hours of searching online, I finally contacted my hosting company to request them to update the user's password to longer hashes.  Apparently, I could not have done it myself.  It seems inconvenient, but at least it's working now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, you will need to reference MySql.Data.dll which is part of MySQL connector to .NET. Download from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).

After this connection is very similar to MS SQL one.

```
private const string ConnectionString = "SERVER=YourServer;DATABASE=YourDB;UID=UserName;PASSWORD=UserPassword;";
using (var mcon = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            using (var cmd = mcon.CreateCommand())
            {
                mcon.Open();
                //you actions
            }
```

Comment: Silly follow-up question, do you put single quotes (') over the IP address, database name, user ID, and password parameters?  I can't seem to get it to work either way.

Comment: in provided c# code - without quotes. For tests try to use signle-worded names, ie without spaces

Comment: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005):

Comment: from the error it seems that ConnString is OK and you have trouble connecting to the MySQL server. Do you have some MySQL console installed, ie Workbench? if yes, try to login using  provided parameters and see what happens

Comment: Yes, I used Workbench and connects fine with the same IP, Username, and password.

Comment: the good part - it is definitely not a connectionString issue. Apart from this take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508749/error-only-occurs-after-publishing-unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-m. Also check if referenced dll is in GAC and is one of a kind, is of right version. Try to create new console project and simply add these lines of code - maybe somehow your current project hasn't updated Conn String yet.

Comment: What and exactly where am I supposed to insert in web.config? Sorry, I don't understand html all that well.

Comment: search your web.config file for the following markup `<trust level="Medium" />` and change word `Medium` to `Full`. If you can find this line just insert it(and change of course) just after `<system.web>`. And this is not html, this is xml. ASP.net is very difficult to understand without knowledge of markup - try to catch up

Comment: When I add <trust level="Full" /> and run it, I get below
Directory Listing -- /WebSite3/

   Thursday, October 03, 2013 01:37 PM        <dir> Bin
   Thursday, October 03, 2013 01:55 PM        1,042 Default2.aspx
   Thursday, October 03, 2013 03:27 PM        1,912 Default2.aspx.cs
   Thursday, October 03, 2013 03:31 PM          333 web.config

Comment: it is better to start new question regarding this error as your listing should be properly detailed. You clearly have valid connection to MySQL DB with some config in project preventing from opening it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its indeed possible

1. For connection  see: http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/
2. For saving settings :http://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/